# Get Current Fragment for Back button Event in FragmentTagManger

Tags: android, android-fragments

I use a FragmentTagManager and now I want to access the currently active Fragment and call a method when the Back button is pressed.

The Fragment that I want to get is a container. Because I am changing Fragments dynamically inside the tabs I need to access the container and call a method from its superclass and cant just pop() from the FragmentStack directly.

How can I access the current Fragment that is displayed in a Tab?

Right now I have this

## Main.java

```
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;




    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_1).setIndicator(getString(R.string.music), null),
                MusicListContainerFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_2).setIndicator(getString(R.string.devices), null),
                DeviceChooserFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_3).setIndicator(getString(R.string.musicplayer), null),
                MusicPlayerFragment.class, null);
}
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        System.out.println(mTabHost.getCurrentTab());
        if(mTabHost.getCurrentTab() == 0){
            System.out.println(getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAB_1));//NULL
            System.out.println(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container));// NULL

        }
    }
```

## Basecontainer.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

## ContainerFragment

```
public class MusicListContainerFragment extends BaseContainerFragment {
    private boolean mIsViewInited;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.base_container, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (!mIsViewInited) {
            mIsViewInited = true;
            initView();
        }
    }

    private void initView() {
        replaceFragment(new MusicListFragment(), false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you found a solution in the meanwhile since your question was posted 3 months ago. Nevertheless I was facing the same problem and came up with this solution.

If you want to override the <- Button in the Actionbar use

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // this takes the user 'back', as if they pressed the left-facing triangle icon on the main android toolbar.
            // if this doesn't work as desired, another possibility is to call `finish()` here.
            if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.activity_profile) instanceof FragmentOfYourChoice) {
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            }
            else
                super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I assume that if you get to the point where is no Fragment in your Backstack you want to trigger the activity pop off your backstack. This is what triggers the "else" branch.

If you want to get the same effect on pressing the actual "Back-Button" (Triangle) you have to override the onBackPressed() method like that.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1)
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use OnBackStackChangedListener to know when there is a fragment stack change, regardless of the method that sets/unsets the fragment stack, as shown:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            //TODO: Handle your stacks changes here
            Log.d(Constants.TAG,"Stack Entry Count: "+getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
        }
    });
```

Regards.-